# Unable to Deploy EAR on Jboss EAP 6.0

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm trying to migrate JBOSS EAP 6.0 from websphere. I have successfully installed JBOSS but getting following errors while deploying EAR on JBOSS:

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I'm just not getting any clue what the error could be. My Log file says :

```
08:09:59,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-21) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "DIDEAR.ear" (runtime-name: "DIDEAR.ear")
08:10:00,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "DIDWeb.war")
08:10:00,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-26) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "DIDEJB.jar")
08:10:02,031 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-beanutils.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,033 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-digester.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,034 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-fileupload.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,035 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-logging.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,036 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry commons-validator.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,037 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jakarta-oro.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.8.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,042 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.5.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:02,043 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /content/DIDEAR.ear/DIDWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.5.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
08:10:03,071 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-22) JBAS012600: Could not load JSF managed bean class: org.apache.myfaces.tiles.example.TilesBacking
08:10:03,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named FindAvailDid in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocal
        java:module/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocalHome
        java:module/FindAvailDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findavaildid.FindAvailDidLocalHome

08:10:03,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named findExistingDid in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocal
        java:module/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocalHome
        java:module/findExistingDid!com.att.umdid.facade.findexistdid.findExistingDidLocalHome

08:10:03,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named EditRange in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocal
        java:module/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocalHome
        java:module/EditRange!com.att.umdid.facade.editRange.EditRangeLocalHome

08:10:03,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named EditCntct in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocal
        java:module/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocalHome
        java:module/EditCntct!com.att.umdid.facade.editCntct.EditCntctLocalHome

08:10:03,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named AddRange in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocal
        java:module/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocalHome
        java:module/AddRange!com.att.umdid.facade.addRange.AddRangeLocalHome

08:10:03,084 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named TransHist in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocal
        java:module/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocalHome
        java:module/TransHist!com.att.umdid.facade.transhist.TransHistLocalHome

08:10:03,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-31) JNDI bindings for session bean named queryDid in deployment unit subdeployment "DIDEJB.jar" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" are as follows:

        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocal
        java:app/DIDEJB/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocal
        java:module/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocal
        java:global/DIDEAR/DIDEJB/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocalHome
        java:app/DIDEJB/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocalHome
        java:module/queryDid!com.att.umdid.facade.querydid.queryDidLocalHome

08:10:03,419 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-22) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."DIDEAR.ear"."DIDWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."DIDEAR.ear"."DIDWeb.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "DIDWeb.war" of deployment "DIDEAR.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.att.umdid.jsf.util.MainServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.DIDEAR.ear.DIDWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: beans/ProfileController
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2412) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1783) [rt.jar:1.6.0_101]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: beans.ProfileController from [Module "deployment.DIDEAR.ear.DIDWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:447) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:414) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 15 more

08:10:03,452 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "DIDEAR.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DIDEAR.ear\".\"DIDWeb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"DIDEAR.ear\".\"DIDWeb.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"DIDWeb.war\" of deployment \"DIDEAR.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.att.umdid.jsf.util.MainServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.DIDEAR.ear.DIDWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: beans/ProfileController
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: beans.ProfileController from [Module \"deployment.DIDEAR.ear.DIDWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid]"
    ]
}
08:10:03,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: DIDEJB.jar) in 62ms
08:10:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: DIDWeb.war) in 203ms
08:10:03,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-24) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment DIDEAR.ear (runtime-name: DIDEAR.ear) in 221ms
08:10:03,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.AddRange.Validator]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditCntct.Validator]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.EditRange.Validator]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.FindAvailDid.Validator]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.TransHist.Validator]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.findExistingDid.ValidatorFactory]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DIDEAR.DIDEJB.queryDid.ValidatorFactory]
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.DIDEAR.DIDEJB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."DIDEAR.ear"."DIDEJB.jar".INSTALL]
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."DIDEAR.ear"."DIDWeb.war".POST_MODULE
```